# Empty result for type=page in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using facebook graph API to get the business detail by "type=page" , but for some business name show  empty result

I have to use url

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q="Business Neme"&type=page

Then I get

{
   "data": [

]
}

please give me any solution to get full information of data using type=page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should URL encode your query as Fluvio shown earlier.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22Business%20Name%22&type=page
```

or

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q="Business Name"&type=page
```

You should get the same result in both queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it returns results just fine:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Business%20Name&type=page
```

Answer (score 1):

I got why graph.facebook showing like this-
If any business profile secure then it will show this type of results.